# regex pattern for match with extension of URL

Tags: javascript, regex

I have these sample URLs:

```
1) example.com/foo.js
2) example.com/foo.js?
3) example.com/foo.js?bar

4) example.com/foo.jsbar
5) example.com/foo.js/bar
```

I want regex js for match with 1, 2, 3 and don't match with 4, 5. with extension.

I use this pattern in [LiveHTTP headers add-on firefox](http://livehttpheaders.mozdev.org/).

Firstly I write this:

```
.js$
```

This just point to the 1.

And this:

```
.js\?
```

Point to the 2, 3.

And this:

```
.js\??$
```

Point to 1, 2.

So finally I write this:

```
.js$|.js\?
```

This works well.

Test online: https://regex101.com/r/BU5IqH/2

Now my question is how can I have a regex with use once `.js` string in the pattern?

Comment: You may use `/\.js(?![^?])/` (not in the regex fiddle, it will work OK in the code itself).

Comment: You can also use `\.js(?:\?|$)`

Comment: The last regex of yours looks like you use it once, is there something I'm missing? `.js$|.js\?` BTW those `.` must be escaped in order to be interpreted as a period. A period without `\\` prefix means: `any single char`  So it should be `\.js$|\.js\?`

Comment: @ctwheels It's clear, please post as answer. and so don't need `?:`

Comment: @zer00ne that regex works but I want once use `.js` string. for simple and short.

Comment: @NabiK.A.Z. Ok, I see, and you want `.js` or `.js?` on return?

Comment: I want to use this pattern in this extension: http://livehttpheaders.mozdev.org/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Brief

My answer is slower than [@Wiktor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47516600/3600709), but more readable. That being said:

- If **readability** is your main concern use my answer.
- If **performance** is your main concern use [@Wiktor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47516600/3600709).

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/BU5IqH/4)

```
\.js(?:\?|$)
```

In the comments below your question you said I could remove `?:`, so in that case the regex would be `\.js(\?|$)`

#### Usage

```js
var a = [ 'example.com/foo.js', 'example.com/foo.js?', 'example.com/foo.js?bar', 'example.com/foo.jsbar', 'example.com/foo.js/bar', 'asasa.com/asasas.css', 'asasa.com/asasas.gif'];
var r = /\.js(?:\?|$)/;
a.forEach(function(s) {
  console.log(s + ': ' + r.test(s));
});
```

---

### Explanation

- `\.js` Match `.js` literally
- `(?:\?|$)` Match either of the following

  - `\?` Match the question mark character `?` literally
  - `$` Assert position at the end of the line

Comment: Thanks, as I said, I don't need to `?:`. and so in my extension (LiveHTTPHeaders) can use `.` instead of `\.`, so finally, the `.js(\?|$)` is works well.

Comment: You need to escape the `.` in regex, it has special meaning. For example, try the regex you've created against the string `example.com/foojs`. Also, I posted (in the line below the regex) that you can use a capture group instead. For the majority of people, however, they'd use the non-capture group instead.

Comment: You correct. and so I use `\.(gif|jpg|ico|css|js|png|mp3)(\?|$)` in LiveHTTPHeaders addons, works well and clear.

Comment: @NabiK.A.Z. that regex works. You can also change `jpg` to `jpe?g` to catch the possibility of the extra `e` in there. I'd also suggest turning on the `i` modifier to ensure the pattern is case-insensitive in case you have files like `.JPG` or `.Jpg`

Comment: `\.js(\?|$)` is the same as `\.js(?![^?])` but is less efficient because it contains an alternation.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I know it's less efficient, but the OP thought that my answer was easier to read and asked me to post it as an answer, so I did just that. I agree your answer is more efficient, but I'll have to agree with the OP that this is easier to read than the answer you provided.

Comment: Ok, I see there is only a requirement to use `js`  only once, so yours is certainly a good answer.

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew I've added information about this in the **Brief** section in my answer for future viewers.

Answer (score 1):

You want to match `.js` that is followed with `?` or end of string.

Use

```
/\.js(?![^?])/
```

**Details**

- `\.` - a dot
- `js` - a `js` substring
- `(?![^?])` - that is not followed with a char other than `?` (so, there can only be a match if there is `?` or end of string) immediately to the right of the current location.

See the JS demo:

```js
var strs = [ 'example.com/foo.js', 'example.com/foo.js?', 'example.com/foo.js?bar', 'example.com/foo.jsbar', 'example.com/foo.js/bar'];
var rx = /\.js(?![^?])/;
for (var s of strs) {
  console.log(s, "=>", rx.test(s));
}
```